# Select All Rows Using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I'm trying to select all the rows out of a database using entity framework for manipulation before they're sent to the form

```
var ptx = [modelname].[tablename]();
ptx.[tablename].Select(????)
```

what goes in the ????

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I used the entitydatasource and it provide everything I needed for what I wanted to do.

`_repository.[tablename].ToList();`

Comment: I wanted to return all rows of a table without a stupid .Where(row => row.Id > 0) and knew it was something simple.  Perfect.  Thanks.

Comment: What is _repository?

Comment: @Andrew `_repository` is the name of the OP's class for the Entity Framework data context.

Answer (score 53):

Entity Framework has one beautiful thing for it, like :

```
var users = context.Users;
```

This will select all rows in Table `User`, then you can use your `.ToList()` etc.

---

**For newbies to Entity Framework, it is like :**

```
PortalEntities context = new PortalEntities();
var users = context.Users;
```

This will **select all rows** in Table `User`

Comment: I would say that  a name like `PortalEntities` is fairly miss-leading, usually it would be `SomethingContext` and you would name the variable context. This because of the naming conventions entity framework have used, so usually you will inherit from the `DbContext`. My statements usually are `using (var context = this.contextFactory.Create()) {}`

Comment: @CallumLinington  :By default, in VS 2015, if you create a context by adding `ADO.NET Entity Data Model` Database First Approach by selecting `(EF Designer from Database)`, it will name your Model as `Model(n)` and your context class name will be  `DatabaseNameEntities`, which is of course being inherited from `DBContext`.

Comment: Fair enough, but I would still say that's missleading, or at least il-named!

Comment: @CallumLinington Not a fire a debate, but [Microsoft's example here,](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896275(v=vs.110).aspx) everywhere it seems to use AdventureWorks**Entities**.

Comment: Yeah, I see they do. I still would never change my mind :) .

Answer (score 22):

How about:

```
using (ModelName context = new ModelName())
{
    var ptx = (from r in context.TableName select r);
}
```

ModelName is the class auto-generated by the designer, which inherits from `ObjectContext`.

Comment: doesnt work! it ask for what model.table is (obviously i put in the entity stuff)

Comment: Note that you can specify such things as `select r.PropertyName` to get actual parts of the entry, should you want specific "columns".

Answer (score 11):

You can use this code to select all rows :

C# :

```
var allStudents = [modelname].[tablename].Select(x => x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply iterate through the DbSet context.tablename

```
foreach(var row in context.tablename)
  Console.WriteLn(row.field);
```

or to evaluate immediately into your own list

```
var allRows = context.tablename.ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's under a `async` method then use `ToListAsync()`

```
        public async Task<List<DocumentTypes>> GetAllDocumentTypes()
        {
            var documentTypes = await _context.DocumentTypes.ToListAsync();

            return documentTypes;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Old post I know, but using `Select(x => x)` can be useful to split the EF Core (or even just Linq) expression up into a query builder.

This is handy for adding dynamic conditions.

For example:

```cs
public async Task<User> GetUser(Guid userId, string userGroup, bool noTracking = false)
{
    IQueryable<User> queryable = _context.Users.Select(x => x);

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userGroup))
        queryable = queryable.Where(x => x.UserGroup == userGroup);

    if(noTracking)
        queryable = queryable.AsNoTracking();

    return await queryable.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.userId == userId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a few ways to do it (Just assume I'm using Dependency Injection for the DbConext)

```
public class Example
{
    private readonly DbContext Context;

    public Example(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
    }

    public DbSetSampleOne[] DbSamples { get; set; }

    public void ExampleMethod DoSomething()
    {
        // Example 1: This will select everything from the entity you want to select
        DbSamples = Context.DbSetSampleOne.ToArray();

        // Example 2: If you want to apply some filtering use the following example
        DbSamples = Context.DbSetSampleOne.ToArray().Where(p => p.Field.Equals("some filter"))

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use:

```
ptx.[tablename].Select( o => true)
```

Comment: so what object do you put it into?

Comment: It will select all objects. "true" - is a condition of object selection.

Comment: Can you add more explanation, links to reference material etc

Comment: (-1) This selects "true" for each row.

Comment: It should be `ptx.[tablename].Where(o => true)`