# What is the equivalent of this select query in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I did search for this and couldn't find a workable answer for me.

What is the equivalent of this query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column=value
```

I need to retrieve all rows that has the same column value

I am new in Entity Framework, sorry if this seems so easy, but i really did my search and found nothing, every solution I found returned only one row while I have 2 rows with same column value

here's one of the many solutions that all only return one record

```
var medicalDetails = db.medicaldetails.Where(m => db.medicaldetails.Any(p =>   p.MDID == id));
return View(medicalDetails.ToList());
```

Comment: At least show some relevant code. You mentioned that you found a solution that returned only one row - post that code so that we can craft an answer that fits your data model, etc.

Comment: @BrendanGreen , Thx for reply. Done

Comment: Hope this link will help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900250/select-all-rows-using-entity-framework

Answer (score 1):

The query you are looking for the LINQ query which would be:

```
myContext.MyTable.Where(t => t.column == value);
```

Or in the case of your example:

```
db.medicaldetails.Where(m => m.MDID == id);
```

Comment: Thx for tryin' to help, but believe me, Where(t => t.column == value); is only returning one record while i have two with the same column value

Comment: DamienG's answer is correct.  Perhaps provide some detail about the values that are in your database.  I suspect either the id's are slightly (but not obviously) different, or your are running a case-sensitive collation in the database.

Comment: sorry guys, I found the Mistake and it was that I'am selecting from DB using another column, not the one i need to select with. 

thanks all for tryin' to help